# codename one: Build-Server stops iOS build with error

Tags: codenameone

I tried to get the CN1LIB for the device calendar to work, after sending an iOS build to codename one, it stopped and gave me an error:

This is the bottom of the huge log he gives me. 
[image]

It seems there is something wrong with the CN1Lib, I added it through the Codename One Propertys and added

```
codename1.arg.android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
```

manually to the "codenameone_settings.properties" at the end of the file. 
Since I only sent the iOS build, this shouldnt be needed anyway, right?

Did someone face the same issue while using this library or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by the `DeviceCalendar` native interface... add this build hint to make it work:

```
ios.add_libs=EventKit.framework
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!